Blender 4.1 : Add selected objects to keying sets or ways to save a selection
I'm a storyboard artist, dabbling in Blender, using it mostly when a background will be easier to handle in 3d, for complicated sets or camera movements. I need to animate a complex group of objects, and I'd like to quickly set a keyframe for all of them when needed, without having to zoom out and select them every time.
Is there a way to call back an object selection quickly?
Keying sets seemed to be the answer, kind of, maybe I missed something but it seems that I can't add a selection of objects all at once, I have to add paths then assign a different object one by one, is that it?

It might be worth investigating putting them all in a Collection. Blender (4) has a Collection Manager addon which allows you to select all objects in the collection from its menu according to the docs.

I think the easiest way to select a group of objects is to move them into a collection and right click on the collection name > Select Objects.
Remember that you can store collections into a collection, and freely move in or out from a collection any object at any time.
In the 3D window press M to move objects into a new or existing collection.
You can then press Shift G (Select similar) > Collection to easily select its content.

